# Oracle SQL - Assign queue of customers to list of Employees

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to distribute list of employees to customers.

**For example:**

> Table 1: List of Employees: A, B & C
>
> Table 2: List of Customers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

**The needed result:**

```
|------------|------------|
| Customers  |  Employees |
|------------|------------|
|   1        |     A      |
|   2        |     B      |
|   3        |     C      |
|   4        |     A      |
|   5        |     B      |
|   6        |     C      |
|   7        |     A      |
|   8        |     B      |
|   9        |     C      |
|------------|------------|
```

Comment: List? Do you mean tables? You have an employee table and a customer table and you are looking for a query to assign the employees to the customers?

Comment: Thanks, I modified to tables.

Comment: Yes looking for query to assign employees to customers in rolling based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a number on the fly to the employees, and the `MOD()` to do the rolling join. For example:

```
select
  c.id,
  e.name
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(order by name) as rn
  from employees t
) e
join customers c on e.rn = 
  mod(rn, (select count(*) from customers)) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Number all rows, then use a modulo function for the join:

```
with e as
(
  select employee, row_number() over (order by employee) as rn
  from employees
)
, c as
(
  select customer, row_number() over (order by customer) as rn
  from customers
)
select c.customer, e.employee
from c
join e on e.rn - 1 = mod(c.rn - 1, (select count(*) from e))
order by c.customer;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=43a6ca7469dff023d5513fa209e33ea7

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MOD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm) function for this purpose. Try below code.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
AS
   SELECT 'A' AS EMP FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B' AS EMP FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'C' AS EMP FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE CUST
AS
   SELECT '1' AS CUST FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '2' AS CUST FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '3' AS CUST FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '4' AS CUST FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '5' AS CUST FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '6' AS CUST FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '7' AS CUST FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '8' AS CUST FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '9' AS CUST FROM DUAL;

  SELECT CUST, EMP
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY EMP) AS ID, EMP
            FROM EMP) EMP
         INNER JOIN CUST ON MOD (TO_NUMBER (CUST.CUST) - 1, 3) = EMP.ID - 1
ORDER BY 1;
```